# What is an "array of arrays"? - Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am following a tutorial about how to make a circuit involving a 4x4 keypad, multiple times a certain "vector array", you might say, has arisen that I do not know the meaning of.

I have searched around, but I have not found anything. Even on the Arduino reference sight.

Here is a code example from the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyprsoB887Y&t=437s).

```c
// "rows" and "cols" being defined as 4 before, so the line is essentially equal to char keys[4][4]

char keys[rows][cols] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', '0'}
};
```

So, what is happening, specifically, it seems like an array of arrays. I see why it would have to be, it couldn't be one variable assigned to multiple arrays, it has to be a containing array that holds them. But I do see how it is declared as 4 by 4, but shouldn't it be 1 by 4? Also, what does `keys[rows][columns]` mean?

Couldn't it just be:

```c
char keys[] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', '0'} 
};
```

Why isn't it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "But I don't see how it is 4 by 4." What dimensions do you see it as?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Haha, I do see it as that, but I think it should be 1 by 4 instead, why isn't it?

Comment: 4x4 means each row is 4 long, and there's 4 rows. I'm not sure why it would be 1x4. And `char keys[]` would suggest that it's a array of characters, but it's not. It's an array of arrays of characters.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ahh, okay, that makes sense, but why shouldn't it be ```char```, are the values not characters, I mean they could be arrays if they are defined like that (direct children, not children of children, that makes sense) but how would you define that, there is no primitive array data type? ```char``` is what the video said.

Comment: Because an array of chars and array of array of chars are different types. If you're familiar with Java, it's like the difference between an `ArrayList<Character>` and an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>`. The outer array doesn't directly contain characters, it contains arrays of characters. If you get the first element of the array, you don't get a character, you get an array of characters.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay that makes sense, so how should have ```keys``` been defined?

Comment: As they have it. `char keys[rows][cols]` means a 2D array of chars where the rows are `cols`-many elements long, and there are `rows`-many rows. [This](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays) might be worth reading. What you're asking about is just array declaration syntax, but the array happens to be nested.

Comment: There's a library associated with that 4x4 array, which needs 4 + 4 pins for the 8 signal lines of that keypad as well. It returns the char specified in that definition, or some NO_KEY ( 0 ), while no key is pressed. Use it and be happy, then look at the details to learn more about 2D arrays in C/C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Couldn't it just be:

```
char keys[] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', '0'} 
};
```

> Why isn't it?

It couldn't be because `char keys[]` specifies an array of type `char`. With the statement above, you are initializing each element to be an array of type `char` itself.

If you wanted to specify it as an array of type `char`, the correct way would be:

```
char keys[] = {
  '1', '2', '3', 'A',
  '4', '5', '6', 'B',
  '7', '8', '9', 'C',
  '*', '0', '#', '0' 
};
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely great! Just to clarify, the reason it is ‘’’char keys[4][4]’’’ is because that means that there are four elements and 4 things in each element and each of those things in the elements are chars

Comment: That is correct, `char keys[4][4]` specifies an array of size 4 where each element is an array of size 4 with elements of type `char`